# Update Salesforce object through ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

I was trying to update account object through ampscript using `UpdateSingleSalesforceObject` this function,the result is returning zero value,is their any permission is need to be provided for accessing/updating object in sfsc?

Comment: Can you please share your code so we can help you understand better what it is your trying to do? You may have issues within your AMPscript first before checking the account object in the CRM

Comment: %%[
set @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Account','00Q00003yAEj','Email','jcc@gmail.com')
]%% %%=v(@result)=%%

Comment: Even i have tried with removing quotes for id field then also facing same issue

Comment: Are you changing the ‘Id’ value to the relevant record you want to update? That Id looks to be only 12 digits... is that the example Id from the documentation?

Comment: I took the id value for the particular record in the account object  and trying to update

Comment: Use the 18 digit ID at the end your URL when viewing the account record in the CRM. I always have success with the 18 digit ID, the other thing to look for is you might be updating a record that requires additional required values and is failing because you are only updating the email field but in fact you need to include the minimal required fields for an update on the account object.

Comment: Thanks ,their is only one manditory field that is ID field.

Comment: Hi Chris,FYI : if my code is wrong it should throw an error,but the result is returning zero value instead of showing 1.

Comment: Thank guys, issue solved

Answer (score 7):

First of all, try to wrap your whole script in a try/catch statement, this will help you [debug AMPscript](https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/08/09/debugging-ampscript/) in case there is an error.

```
<script runat="server">
  Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");

  try{

</script>

%%[

  set @id = "00Q00003yAEj"
  set @email = "jcc@gmail.com"
  set @updateRecord = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject(
      "Account",@id,
      "Email", @email
     )

]%%

Status: %%=v(@updateRecord)=%%  

<script runat="server">
  }catch(e){
    Write(Stringify(e));
  }
</script>
```

And now why above won't work?

1. You said that you wanted to update an Account, but you are clearly using a Lead Id in your script (lead Ids start with `00Q`, while account Ids would start with something like `001`). 
   Make sure that you are using the correct object with the correct Id.
2. There is no way that the Id is [12 digits long](http://www.sfdcpoint.com/salesforce/salesforce-id-15-digit-18-digit-conversion/). It's always either 15 or 18, but never 12 digits. Please check the Id and make sure that you are using the correct one.